# I need to sum up data obtained by "foreach" function by using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried to use `Javascript` to sum up data obtained by `foreach` function as described below but I have failed, anyone with support p'se..

This is the code:

```
<tbody>  
 <?php
 $running_year = 2018;
 $count = 1;
 $query = $this->db->get('teacher')->result_array();
 foreach ($query as $row):
 ?> 

<td class="count-me">
    <?php 
    $teacher_id = $this->db->get_where('subject',
    array('teacher_id' => $row['teacher_id'],'year'=> 
    $running_year))->result_array();
    foreach ($teacher_id as $row1):?>

    <?php
    $subject_no = $this->db->get_where('class_routine', 
    array('subject_id' => $row1['subject_id']));

    $test = $subject_no->num_rows();
    echo $test;
    ?>
    </br>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</td>


<td id="countit">
  <?php                   
  $teacher_id = $this->db->get_where('subject', 
  array('teacher_id' =>$row['teacher_id'], 'year'=> $running_year))->result_array();
  foreach ($teacher_id as $row1):?>


     //I need the results (that is sum) to be here

  </br>
  <?php endforeach;;?>
 </td>

 <?php endforeach;?>

</tbody>
```

This below is the javascript

```
<script>
      var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
      var sum = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
      if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
      sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
      document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';

    </script>
```

The results are these one

[image: p'se click here to see the result]

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic of your code is correct. I believe PHP response came late and javascript executes first as being client side. You may try jquery and 
$(document).ready(function()

```
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
          var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
          console.log(tds);
          var sum = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
          if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
          sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }

            alert(sum);
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: If I write number manually like <td>5</td> it works. But the number  should be called from database by foreach as $row  @azizsagi

Comment: yes, can you please tell me what is the format of returning number?

Comment: Ok, The results shown in a table (no. of periods per week)  are the values of $test variable, but if i try to write a number manually may be 5 it works, but what i need is to get the sum by adding $test values obtained directly from a database, can you do that?  That is why i mentioned "foreach" function @azizsagi

Comment: I think problem is that javascript runs first and data from database loads later. You may try by adding $( document ).ready({}); or $( document ).on({ }); for that you need to add jquery in your page.

Comment: P'se may you edit your answer so that I can get it more clearly